# Field Template Loop Counter Override Problem

Tags: theming, entities, 8

I'm using a template override for field.html.twig

I'm simply trying to generate a data-depth attribute that takes the index of the loop and multiplying it by 0.2.

Here is the Twig markup:

```
<div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--items') }}>
  {% for item in items %}
    {% set i = loop.index %}
    {% set depth = i * 0.2 %}
    <div {{ item.attributes.addClass('field--item') }} {{ attributes.setAttribute('data-type', 'test') }} {{ attributes.setAttribute('data-depth', depth) }}>
      {{ item.content }}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Here is the HTML output:

```
<div data-quickedit-field-id="paragraph/2/field_test/en/default" class="field field--name-field-test-image field--type-image field--label-hidden field--items">
  <div class="field--item" data-type="test" data-depth="0.2">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/2016-08/5.png">
  </div>
  <div class="field--item" data-type="test" data-depth="0.2">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/2016-08/4.png">
  </div>
  <div class="field--item" data-type="test" data-depth="0.4">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/2016-08/3.png">
  </div>
  <div class="field--item" data-type="test" data-depth="0.6">       
    <img src="/sites/default/files/2016-08/2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="field--item" data-type="test" data-depth="0.8">
    <img src="/sites/default/files/2016-08/1.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the first two iterations are the same - they have 0.2 as the data-depth which is incorrect it, the sequence should be 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8 and 1.0. Is this is a bug with drupal? Or am I totally missing something here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `loop.index0` instead?

Comment: Yep. Doesn't work. It states here that index0 starts the iteration with the initial value of 0. I don't want this. As i've used .index to start the iteration with value 1. http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable

Comment: Yeah I thought I'd read somewhere that you need to use `index0` when working with zero-based php arrays. Must be mistaken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and it works for me:

```
   {% for item in items %}
        {% set counter = ( counter | default(0) ) + 0.2 %}
        <div{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_classes) }} data-depth="{{ counter }}">{{ item.content }}</div>
      {% endfor %}
```

This renders as:

```
<div class="field field--name-field-gallery-ref" data-depth="0.2">
...
<div class="field field--name-field-gallery-ref" data-depth="0.4">
...
```

Note, I did not get the repeating depth numbers as you did above.

Comment: This works for me. Thanks. Any idea why my version wasn't working. I think it was maybe down to the use of the {{ attributes.setAttribute('data-depth', depth) }} code?

Comment: Welcome, I'm not sure but I'd agree with your assessment having to do with the attributes.